# Is .NET 3.5.1 Supported on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, .net-3.5

I can't find any documentation regarding this, take a look at..

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/framework_faq/en-us

> **.NET Framework 3.5 SP1:** Beginning with .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack
>   1 (SP1) the .NET Framework is defined as a component instead of an
>   independent product. So, support for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is driven
>   by the support lifecycle policy of the Windows operating system (i.e.
>   when Windows is in the Mainstream Support phase or Extended Support
>   phase, so are its components). When a product such as Windows reaches
>   the end of support, so do its related components. .NET Framework 3.5
>   SP1 is supported on Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista SP2,
>   Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1,
>   Windows 8.1 Update, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, and
>   Windows 10 according to the end of support date for each operating
>   system.

Windows 2016 Server is not listed, but I have a feeling maybe the document isn't updated to reflect the new server OS? I know as I was able to add it as a "Feature" but it wasn't installed as part of the OS.

If anyone has any updated information regarding this, It will be beneficial to me and the community.

Comment: Yes, same as Windows 10.  .NET 3.5/CLR 2.0 will be around and supported for quite a long time.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Net Framework 3.5 is working on Windows Server 2016, I have it installed on my Servers. So far, we haven't had any reported issues from our programmers.

Remember, You need to install it as a server feature. (Make sure to **Specify an alternate source path** during the installation. You need to mount your Windows 2016 Disk and set the path to Drive:\sources\sxs).

Comment: If you don't specify an alternate source, Windows should download the installer via Windows Update. Which requires the prerequisites for installing any server roles that the Windows Update service is enabled. It's doesn't actually require that the update is there, just that the service is enabled.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but are you actually getting any patches (security or otherwise) for .Net on Server 2016? I'm looking in SCCM and I'm not seeing any listed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SCCM 2016 to downloading and deploying Security and Critical updates for .Net frameworks on Windows Servers 2016. Make sure to use SCCM 2016 or latest RU version. SCCM 2012 do not support Windows Server 2016.

Comment: FWIW, This is kind of BS, since several Microsft utilities still rely on it.  Right now I'm trying to use the RSKeyMgmt tool for SQL 2016, which requires .NET 3.5.1 which I now need to remount an ISO for.  They ought to have recompiled all of their SQL 2016 (and other) utilities before starting to orphan 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has updated their FAQ

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17455/lifecycle-faq-net-framework

> .NET Framework 3.5 SP1: Beginning with .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack
>   1 (SP1) the .NET Framework is defined as a component instead of an
>   independent product. So, support for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is driven
>   by the Lifecycle Policy of the Windows operating system (that is, when
>   Windows is in the Mainstream Support phase or Extended Support phase,
>   so are its components). When a product such as Windows reaches the end
>   of support, so do its related components. .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is
>   supported on Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008
>   SP2, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8.1 Update, Windows Server
>   2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 10, and Windows Server 2016
>   according to the end of support date for each operating system.